# Error when accessing constructor in embedded mongoid model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have an emmbedded mongoid class "Option" which I would like to initialize the following way:

@option = @event.options.new('yes')

```
class Option

  include Mongoid::Document

  field :content, type: String

  embedded_in :event

  def initialize(content)
    @content = content
  end
end
```

So I added the consctructor above but I get the following error:

> NoMethodError in EventsController#new undefined method `[]' for
>   nil:NilClass

What am I missing?

Using rails 4...

EDIT: As requested here is the controller code:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      # GET /events
      # GET /events.json
      def index
        @events = Event.all
      end

      # GET /events/1
      # GET /events/1.json
      def show
      end

      # GET /events/new
      def new
        @event = Event.new

        @event.invitees << @event.invitees.build
        @event.options  << @event.options.build
        #end
      end

      # GET /events/1/edit
      def edit
      end

      # POST /events
      # POST /events.json
      def create

        # TODO: adapt event_params and filter right
        #@event = Event.create(event_params)
        @event = Event.new(params[:event])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @event.save
            #TODO: Save users attached to event in user collection
            format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @event }
          else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /events/1
      # PATCH/PUT /events/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @event.update(event_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
          else
            format.html { render action: 'edit' }
            format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /events/1
      # DELETE /events/1.json
      def destroy
        @event.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to events_url }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_event
          @event = Event.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def event_params
          params.require(:event).permit(:name, :description, :date)
        end
    end
```

Comment: please provide your controller code. (EventsController#new)

Comment: As requested in the edit above

Answer (score 1):

That is because your `field :content, type: String` is not initialized yet

You'll need to call `super()` in the first line of your `initialize` method, then you'll be able to change the value of `content` in the constructor

Try:

```
def initialize(content)
   super()
   self.content = content
end
```